# Getting "error: cannot estimate gas" on Ethereum mainnet but not on Rinkeby?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to execute a gnosis safe transaction on Ethereum mainnet but consistently this error -

```js
error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={\"code\":3,\"message\":\"execution reverted: GS026\",\"data\":\"0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054753303236000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\"}, method=\"estimateGas\", transaction={\"from\":\"0xf6754b8a58BFb62C89827bC31be363b608b39bE3\",\"to\":\"0xb76Bed0B12062F3668AfD7d300B2A193a297cee3\",\"data\":\"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\",\"accessList\":null}, code=UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, version=providers/5.5.3)",
    "level": "error"
}
```

The same code is working fine on Rinkeby but the same code giving this error on the mainnet. Not able to understand the reason.

Currently having an issue with this transaction

```js
safeAddress: 0xb76Bed0B12062F3668AfD7d300B2A193a297cee3
safeTxHash: 0xd3773e40ff1078e5b836447006099e239967c21bde51b2c948002089b9a9e277
network: Ethereum Mainnet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction `0xd3773e40ff1078e5b836447006099e239967c21bde51b2c948002089b9a9e277` has nonce 2 but the Safe `0xb76Bed0B12062F3668AfD7d300B2A193a297cee3` nonce is 1. You need to execute a transaction with nonce 1 first

Comment: ya, the issue had resolved, we had a pending transaction with lower nonce and just forgot to execute that first. Thank you for your time and response.